# PDF.js Error during font loading

Tags: javascript, pdf

I'm having issue with displaying the following PDF file.

[https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=BA2E9E42862EC5A7%21280](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=BA2E9E42862EC5A7!280)

What I'm trying to do is to pass this file as Uint8Array to PDF.js.
And I'm getting the following stacktrace:

```
Warning: Setting up fake worker. pdf.js:106
(while reading XRef): TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined        pdf.worker.js:5281
Error
at XRefParseExceptionClosure (http://127.0.0.1:8090/assets/js/vendor/pdf-   js/pdf.worker.js:310:34)
at pdfjsWrapper (http://127.0.0.1:8090/assets/js/vendor/pdf-js/pdf.worker.js:315:3)
at http://127.0.0.1:8090/assets/js/vendor/pdf-js/pdf.worker.js:39174:4  pdf.worker.js:3801
Warning: Indexing all PDF objects pdf.worker.js:106
Error: Bad FCHECK in flate stream: 120, 253 pdf.worker.js:122
at error (http://127.0.0.1:8090/assets/js/vendor/pdf-js/pdf.worker.js:124:7)
at Object.FlateStream (http://127.0.0.1:8090/assets/js/vendor/pdf- js/pdf.worker.js:32044:7)
at Object.Parser_makeFilter [as makeFilter]   (http://127.0.0.1:8090/assets/js/vendor/pdf-js/pdf.worker.js:31227:16)
at Object.Parser_filter [as filter] (http://127.0.0.1:8090/assets/js/vendor/pdf- js/pdf.worker.js:31212:25)
at Object.Parser_makeStream [as makeStream]  (http://127.0.0.1:8090/assets/js/vendor/pdf-js/pdf.worker.js:31192:21)
at Object.Parser_getObj [as getObj] (http://127.0.0.1:8090/assets/js/vendor/pdf-    js/pdf.worker.js:31028:18)
at Object.XRef_fetch [as fetch] (http://127.0.0.1:8090/assets/js/vendor/pdf- js/pdf.worker.js:5352:22)
at Object.XRef_fetchIfRef [as fetchIfRef] (http://127.0.0.1:8090/assets/js/vendor/pdf-js/pdf.worker.js:5298:19)
at Object.Dict_get [as get] (http://127.0.0.1:8090/assets/js/vendor/pdf-js/pdf.worker.js:4466:28) pdf.worker.js:124
Warning: Error during font loading: Bad FCHECK in flate stream: 120, 253 pdf.js:106
page=1 - getOperatorList: time=4ms, len=0 pdf.worker.js:34290
```

It's working fine when I'm opening it with Acrobat Reader. Moreover it's also works fine in PDF.js if I'm opening it from URI previously saving it to file system.

For conversion I'm using the following function:

```
function conver(str) {
  var length = str.length;
  var bytes = new Uint8Array(length);
  for (var n = 0; n < length; ++n)
     bytes[n] = str.charCodeAt(n) & 0xFF;
  return bytes;
```

}

Can you advise me something on that?

**UPDATE:** It's seems to be the problem with the font I'm using -  'Franklin Gothic Medium Cond', if I'm trying to render the same one with Helvetica it's working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem using base64 encoding at my server side. So I'm using this function for converting from base64 to typed array:

```
function convert (base64) {
    var raw = atob(base64);
    var arr = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(raw.length));
    for (var i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return arr;
}
```